# Sync Software and Config files across multiple Machines

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sync

### Problem

I currently use both a desktop and a laptop which both require WSL to be run on them.
Often times I install something at school and have to manually redo it at home.

Optimally I could also sync or export (maybe similar to package.json and npm install) installed software without sharing possibly sensitive dotfiles to classmates.

### What I've found

Mackup or unison both seem to be quite close to what I need.
My two personal Devices aren't in the same network at any time.

##### What are you using/would recommend to someone relatively new to linux/wsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To someone relatively new?

1. Put the data onto some online location (Google Drive, DropBox, NextCloud, etc) and simply sync manually. An unskilled user should not bother using sync tools that they do not have the skills to troubleshoot or maintain when something goes wrong.
2. Software, settings, and configurations are different. Automatically synchronizing software is even more complex, and should be avoided unless you are learning to be an enterprise-level sysadmin. Simply keep notes about installs, settings, ande customizations in the same online location.